# Selecting a particular XML node and replacing the inner text of the node using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to replace the string `>=` with `&GE;` in an XML document using C#. I need to select a particular node from a large XML document. How can I do this in code?

Here is the sample XML:

```xml
<Symbol>
  <EA_Qualitative type="num" attributeId="Symbol2">
    <Items>
      <Item>>=</Item>
    </Items>
  </EA_Qualitative>
</Symbol>
```

C# code :

```cs
string cvalue = csDoc.InnerXml.ToString(); //csDoc is the Xml document
stringc cvchild = csDoc.ChildNodes.ToString();

cvchild = csDoc.SelectSingleNode("<Symbol>").InnerText.Replace(">=","&GE;");

message.appendLine("<Item>" + cvchild + "<Item>");
```

Comment: You can't do it in xml because it won't load with the error.  Read file using StreamReader() and then replace the text.

Comment: Could you elaborate your point .The xml is a log file , cannot read the file directly.

Comment: You cannot read it using XmlDocument class or XDocument class when you have non-valid xml innertext characters like ">"

Comment: So how is possible with a log file when it is automatically generated

Comment: As I said you can't from an XmlDocument orXDocument.  You have to get it into a string and do the replacement in the string.  Once you get it fixed you can then read string into an XmlDocument or XDocument.

Comment: please specify an example if possile